# how to run a service which updates the appwidget?

Tags: android, android-widget

I am having a home screen widget and i want to run a background service which does all the fetching from url and should update all the widgets on the home screen corresponding to the provider i have created it.

how to do it? it seems that i unable to access appwidget or the context from the service.

any help?

Answer (score 0):

my response here should be helpful to you [android appwidget won't update from activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424723/android-appwidget-wont-update-from-activity/4424845#4424845)